# How to plot a bar graph for each value of a groupby result with the count of the distinct values in another column in each group in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, bar-chart

I have a dataframe as follows:

[image]

I want to groupby the Ngram. Then in each group, there will be different values of DocFreq - 2, 3, 4..etc. I want the count of each distinct value of DocFreq in each group.
For example, in the image there are 7 trigrams. Out of these 7,

```
1 trigram has docFreq = 7
1 trigram has docFreq = 4
1 trigram has docFreq = 3
4 trigrams have docFreq = 2
```

I want to have a bar graph for a trigram that will have x axis as the docFreq values and the y axis as the number of trigrams with that document frequency. (Such bar graphs for every ngram)

I have done the following with the help of another stackoverflow answer:

```
dfu = df.groupby(['Ngram']).DocFreq.value_counts().unstack()
```

This yields the following table :

[image]

I want to have individual bar graphs for every n-gram. So essentially every row in this table should be a plot with docFreq being the x axis and the value being the height of each bar.
But I can't figure out how to create these individual bar graphs from this table. Or whether to even try creating from this table or if there is any way I can just use the main dataframe and groupby and value_counts and make the bar graph.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the result in a crude manner.

```
x = df.loc[(df['Ngram']==3) & (df['DocFreq'] > 1), ['Term', 'DocFreq', 'Ngram']]
xt = x.groupby(['DocFreq']).size()
ax = xt.iloc[:30].plot.bar(figsize = (40,30),rot = 0, )
ax.set_xlabel("Document Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Count of documents having the 'DocFreq' number of duplicates")
```

This gives me the bar graph for a tri-gram yielding the following :
[image]
I have taken only till 30 because if I take the whole length then the bar graph gets messy.
So for now I'm just going to perform this for all the n-grams separately. Hopefully, someone can come up with a faster method to generate the graphs of all n-grams more efficiently and in a prettier way.

Thank you.